# What is the owner parameter in the live data observer when put in an onClickListener?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclicklistener, android-livedata

When clicking a button I want to make a `query` for my `Room` data. I have an `observable` on my data that I put in the `OnClickListener`. The `observer` works fine outside of the `OnClickListener` method, but inside of it, the owner parameter is a mismatch.

`Android Studio` asks for `android.arch.lifecycle.LifeCycleOwner` but says that it gets `android.view.View.OnClickListener`.

```
showAllButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        //The "this" parameter is underlined red

            myViewModel.getAllDataVM().observe(    this   , new Observer<List<MyRoomEntity>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable List<MyRoomEntity> myRoomEntities) {
                    //myAdapter.setList( myRoomEntities );

                    Log.d("TAG", "OBSERVED");
                    if(myRoomEntities != null) {
                        for(MyRoomEntity item: myRoomEntities) {
                            Log.d("TAG ROOM ", "" + item.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            } );
        }
    } );//End Button
```

`this` is underlined in red, which is the `owner` parameter. I have tried using `context`, `application`, etc, but nothing works. Maybe it's not possible to have an observer inside an `OnClickListener`, but what do I do then?

Comment: The problem here is that "this" refers to the new View.OnClickListener() instance that you made, hence the error for mismatched parameters. Try to either pass the context by constructor or use ScaningActivity.this instead of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common error that is easily fixable. The `this` keyword is currently referring to the `View.OnClickListener` which is **not** one of the arguments for `.observe()`. Hence, to fix this problem, you simply have to replace `this` with:

1. `getApplicationContext()`
2. `MyActivity.this`

Your code should be mostly unchanged:

```
 myViewModel.getAllDataVM().observe(getApplicationContext(), new Observer<List<MyRoomEntity>>() {
     @Override
     public void onChanged(@Nullable List<MyRoomEntity> myRoomEntities) {
         //.....
```

Comment: The second suggestion worked great! Hadn't tried that before. Thank you so much for helping me out @Ishaan :)